# Foreign key constraint not working despite PRAGMA

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my code. It's SQLITE3 in Python 3. Posted in both DB administrators and here, wasn't sure if this was a Python mistake or SQLITE mistake.

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('BEGIN')
    c.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE Product(maker int, model int primary key, type varchar(255))')
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE PC(model int references Product(model) on delete cascade, speed int, ram int, hd int, price int check (price>=0))')
```

and then I do

```
c.execute('DELETE FROM Product WHERE model=?', (args[0],))
```

but only the `Product` entry is deleted, not the `PC` one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you should use one `c.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;CREATE TABLE Product(maker int, model int primary key, type varchar(255));...;");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PRAGMA foreign_keys`](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) will silently fail if executed in a transaction, which you start with the `BEGIN` statement.

> This pragma is a no-op within a transaction; foreign key constraint enforcement may only be enabled or disabled when there is no pending BEGIN or SAVEPOINT.